# Finding what the report subscription error is in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I've created a simple report in SSRS, and then tried my hand out with a data driven subscription.
I can verify that the subscription runs on the 'My Subscriptions' page, but under status it says there is one error.

How do I find out what this error is?

Comment: Are there any interesting entries in the windows event logs and SQL Server logs?

Comment: I wasn't able to find any, which surprises me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

received this answer from stackoverflow which helped me find info on the errors:

> You need to look in the "Report Server Execution Log" which is a particular SQL Reporting Services log file.
>
> See [Reporting Services Log Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157403.aspx) for details.